# alternatingRowColors of a qtableview that uses a QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: c++, qt

I need help to use alternatingRowColors of a qtableview that uses a QSortFilterProxyModel.

The filter of the QSortFilterProxyModel ruins the alternating color of my table view.

I guess that I will need to paint background of the row every time that the filter is applied.

What would be the best way to do this?

ps.: I'm using a class that inherits from QStyledItemDelegate.
Can I do something in the paint method to do it?

Thanks in advance.

ADD:

I try this on my model.

```
QVariant FilterProxyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const{
QVariant v = QSortFilterProxyModel::data(index, role);
if (role == Qt::BackgroundColorRole)
  {
if(index.row() % 2 == 0)
  return QVariant(QColor(255,255,255));
else
  return QVariant(QColor(248,248,248));
}
return (v);
}
```

This solves the alternate row color problem but 
it seems that this is canceling ItemDelegate::paint function that I implemented.

There is other way to do it??

Comment: There is also a `Qt::BackgroundRole`, and you can use it in your model's data() function to define the background color of your items.

Comment: Why does the filter ruin the background?

Comment: @vahancho I added my implementation of date () and some information on the Question. I need a little more help. Can you help me?

Comment: @RobbieE one example of what happens is: There is 3 rows on my table. Row 1 and 3 has color, and row 2 is white. When filtermodel hides the second row,  remains two rows with color. What I want is that the third row becomes white. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm for alternating the colour is not data dependent, you are only using two colours for the entire dataset. In such cases, you should not be using your model to determine the background colour, let the view do this automatically by calling `QAbstractItemView::setAlternatingRowColors(true)`

The Delegate should also not be used to draw the cells of a view, that's not the point of the delegate.

It should be used to handle the editors only, the widgets that you use to edit data. These widgets are created when an edit trigger has been detected by the view and the editor is destroyed once the editing is finished. The drawing of the rest of the data in the view are not affected by the painting of the delegate's editor.

Comment: I have already set setAlternatingRowColors to true in my view. And it works but when the filter is applied happens that situation that I mentioned.

Comment: That is why I said you should not be setting the background colour in the model, the view can do it already.

Comment: Yes, the view do this for me but I guess that when the filter  is applied it just hide the row and the view doesn't refresh the row color, so I may have two rows with the same color in sequence. I want to know how can I solve the rows with the same color in sequence problem.

Comment: You didn't understand me. Your filter is returning colour data for the Qt::BackgroundRole. It should not. The view must be responsible for the alternate colour, not the model, not the filter, not the proxy, not any class derived from QAbstractItemModel.

Comment: Sorry. My English is nt very good and thank you for helping me. The data method was just a attempt to solve my problem. I'm already remove it from my application. I don't know how to make the view do that. I have a model class derived from QSortFilterProxyModel and I'm implementing the filterAcceptsRow. And the model is doing just that different from the normal. I don't know why setAlternatingRowColors(true) is not working after applied the filter.